# jQuery behavior on variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am customizing the jump example of markjs.
[markjs_example](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/973gdh8g/)

I have added some actions when I press the next button at the last instance of searched term, at this point it works.

```
if(currentIndex == 0 && jQuery(this).is($nextBtn)){
    if(confirm("No more instances found! Go to the next page?")){
      alert("NEXT PAGE");
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to change the search behavior if I have reached the last marked word so I have added a variable `i` that I increment if I have reached the last marked word.

So i = 1 if nothing happened.
And i = 2 if I have reached the last word and pressed next, aka I am on the imaginary next page

To test all this I have added console log as you will see in the jsfiddle.
**The problem is :** it never prompt "page2" in the console, and i stays at 1, why?

[jsfiddle_of_my_code](https://jsfiddle.net/973gdh8g/451/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in if(i === 1) and else are evaluated only first time when page loads, and only the if condition is executed and registers the unmark method. Once i changes to 2 , the else condition for i===2 is never executed, therefore the second method $content.unmark is not registered or executed

You need to call unmark method once i changes to 2.
As in the code below,

```js
jQuery(function() {
    
            // the input field
            $input = jQuery("input[type=\'search\']");
              // clear button
              var $clearBtn = jQuery("button[data-search=\'clear\']"),
              // prev button
              $prevBtn = jQuery("button[data-search=\'prev\']"),
              // next button
              $nextBtn = jQuery("button[data-search=\'next\']"),
              // the context where to search
              $content = jQuery(".content"),
              // jQuery object to save <mark> elements
              $results,
              // the class that will be appended to the current
              // focused element
              currentClass = "current",
              // top offset for the jump (the search bar)
              offsetTop = 50,
              // the current index of the focused element
              currentIndex = 0,
              //2 after last occurence reached
              i = 1;
              
              
          
            /**
             * Jumps to the element matching the currentIndex
             */
            function jumpTo() {
              if ($results && $results.length) {
              
                var position,
                  $current = $results.eq(currentIndex);
                    
                $results.removeClass(currentClass);
                if ($current.length) {
                  $current.addClass(currentClass);
                  position = $current.offset().top - offsetTop - 100;
                  window.scrollTo(0, position);
                }
              }
            }
                /**
                 * Searches for the entered keyword in the
                 * specified context on input
                 */
                 $input.on("input", function() {
                    searchVal = this.value;
                    $content.unmark({
                        done: function() {
                        $content.mark(searchVal, {
                            separateWordSearch: true,
                            done: function() {
                            $results = $content.find("mark");
                            currentIndex = 0;
                            console.log("page1");
                            console.log(i);
                            jumpTo();
                            }
                        });
                        }
                    });
                    });
                    
                    
            function registerClear(){
              $content.unmark({
                    done: function() {
                    $content.mark(searchVal, {
                        separateWordSearch: true,
                        done: function() {
                        $results = $content.find("mark");
                        currentIndex = 0;
                        console.log(searchVal);
                        console.log("page2");
                        jumpTo();
                        }
                    });
                    }
                });
            }        
                
                
           
            /**
             * Clears the search
             */
            $clearBtn.on("click", function() {
              $content.unmark();
              $input.val("").focus();
            });
          
            /**
             * Next and previous search jump to
             */
            $nextBtn.add($prevBtn).on("click", function() {
              if ($results.length) {
                currentIndex += jQuery(this).is($prevBtn) ? -1 : 1;
                if (currentIndex < 0) {
                  currentIndex = $results.length - 1;
                }
                if (currentIndex > $results.length - 1) {
                  currentIndex = 0;
                }
                //if next pressed after last instance
                if(currentIndex == 0 && jQuery(this).is($nextBtn)){
                  if(confirm("No more instances found! Go to the next page?")){
                    alert("NEXT PAGE");
                    i = 2;
                    registerClear();
                  }else{
                      //do nothing
                  }
                }
                jumpTo();
              }
            });
          
          });
```

Comment: Thank you for all the explainations and the solution!